# Finding the area of the intersection of two circles

Tags: geometry, gre-exam

The following is problem 8 from a GRE exam found [here](http://www.naec.ge/images/doc/documents/GRE-2010-MAT.pdf).

[image]

The problem states that the two circles with radius $r=3$ intersect each other such that the area of the darkened region is equal to the sum of areas of the dashed regions. Find the area of the darkened region. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the "area of darked figure is equal 1 sum of areas of dashed circles?" Are you saying the area of the darkened figure is equal to the sum of the areas of both dashed figures?

Comment: yes exactly   it is so

Comment: Hint: that the problem uses circles isn't really important, it would work just as well with two overlapping squares or rectangles or triangles (with the same area).

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I tried to improve the formatting of your question user3196. If anything is not to your liking, please don't hesitate to rollback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denote the area of the darkened region as $A$, and denote the area of each of the dashed regions as $B$. The areas of the dashed regions are equal since the two intersecting circles have equal area. So $A+B=\pi\cdot 3^2=9\pi$, since $A$ and $B$ added give the area of the circle with radius $3$. But based on given information, $A=2B$. Can you proceed from there?

Comment: yes it means that area of darkened circle is 6*PI   which  is also in answer too thanks once again.i am preparing   for exams in general abilities  for gain   grant from states and it is exams  for master programs thanks @yunone

Comment: @user3196 glad to help. Good luck with your preparation.